# Is there an anti-spam advantage of using reCAPTCHA module instead of just CAPTCHA by itself?

Tags: 7

What is the advantage of using the [reCAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module over the plain old [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module?

Are spam bots less likely likely to beat reCAPTCHA?

Thanks

Comment: Recaptcha module depends on the plain old Captcha module. This recaptcha module is actually integrating the recaptcha.net service with the captcha module.

Comment: Do you think it offers a better level of anti-span protection?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about differences between mechanisms that are not Drupal-dependent. Both reCaptcha and traditional Captcha can be used with Drupal and in any other CMS or website, and differences will be exactly the same, so this is not a Drupal question.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest advantages of using reCaptcha is the built in support for people who are visually impaired and the ability to evolve without your intervention. ReCaptcha continuously changes to fight of spam bots.